# Opening microscopy image files in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

Does anybody know hohw to open microscopy image files in MATLAB without exporting them into TIFF images, in the microscope software? I have figured it out that the command "bfopen" will open the files, but its a structure and I don't know how to read them after opening them with "bfopen".

Comment: I'd recommend asking this on the Open Microscopy Environment community support resources, such as the forums or email lists. The links to these are at https://www.openmicroscopy.org/support/

Comment: unclear because the file format wasn't given